# How can I integrate a Facebook Permission Url into my PHP code?

Tags: php, facebook-wall

I have created an app that allows user post a comment on their wall after they login (they are prompted as per Facebook Guidelines).

My Application lies on my website and uses PHP - and requires a Facebook login/logout - which I did.

It works fine when I use my user account - but when a friend tries to use the app the Application doesn't let him. So I give him this following URL:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
client_id=140372229420521
&redirect_uri=http://www.magimagi.com/login/uploadtopage2.php
&scope=manage_pages,offline_access,user_photos,read_stream,publish_stream,manage_pages,offline_access,share_item
```

So this means every time I want someone to use my app I must give them the said link.

This is my PHP code.

```
// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
 try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');


  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}


if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(   array(
       'scope' => 'publish_stream'
      ));
}
```

How can I integrate the above URL into my PHP code so that when the user does a login, it will have the correct permissions immediately, without me having to give out the link please?

I already read the documentations and enabled the permissions but I am still lost.

I am still new here, so please forgive my ignorance. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just put the login URL in the href attribute of a link element, let the user click it – and when the redirect occurs, you have your permissions. (Or not, if the user descides not to grant them. For info on how to handle that, please see docs.)

Comment: How can I integrate it with the login of the existing Facebook login please?

Comment: Basic stuff like that, you should really be able to handle yourself.

Comment: echo "<a href=https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=140372229420521&redirect_uri=http://www.magimagi.com/login/uploadtopage2.php&scope=manage_pages,offline_access,user_photos,read_stream,publish_stream,manage_pages,offline_access,share_item>Logout with Facebook</a>";

Comment: try `echo "<a href=\"your_long_url\">Logout with Facebook</a>";` Notice the escaped quotation marks. This is basic HTML stuff.